# Show JSON response through binding (Xamarin forms)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, jsonresponse, xamarin-binding

[image: i want this below data to be showed in the above fields]i showed json response now i want to it to show like in a proper format in the editor section. Below is my code: (i am trying this from past two days but i dont know how to show this in a proper format)

Page 1 from where i passed the json data:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    public String test;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //     Task.Run(async () => await GetinfoAsync());
        GetinfoAsync();
    }

    public async Task GetinfoAsync()
    {
        var responseString = await client.GetStringAsync("https://reqres.in/api/users/2");

        UserResponse result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserResponse>(responseString);
        if (result != null)
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                test = dis.Text = "Id:- " + result.Data.id + "\nEmail:- " + result.Data.email + "\nFirst Name:- " + result.Data.first_name + "\nLast Name:- " + result.Data.last_name + "\nImage:- " + result.Data.avatar; dis.Text = test;
            });
        }
    }

    private async void click_me(Object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        await this.Navigation.PushAsync(new Data(test));
    }
```

Page 2 where i get the json data from page 1

```
public partial class Data : ContentPage
{
    public MyUser obj;
    public String show;

    public Data(String test)
    {
        show = test;
        InitializeComponent();
        displaylabel.Text = test;
    }
}
```

Page 2 Xaml

```
<StackLayout Padding="20">
    <Editor Text="{Binding obj.id}"   IsReadOnly="True"/>
    <Editor Text="{Binding obj.first_name}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    <Editor Text="{Binding obj.last_name}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    <Editor Text="{Binding obj.email}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    <Editor Text="Image" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    <Image  HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" Source="{Binding obj.avatar}"/>

    <Label Text="show json"
        x:Name="displaylabel"
    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

</StackLayout>
```

myuser.cs

```
public class MyUser
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string avatar { get; set; }
}

public class UserResponse
{
    public MyUser Data { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It'd be helpful if you showed us the results and described how the actual result deviates from your expectations.

Comment: Could you show the rest of `Data.xaml` or however it is called?

Comment: you are talking about that design page?

Comment: *Page 2 XAML* - this is the one you are expecting the data to be displayed on, isn't it?

Comment: i did but it helped me in just showing that data not in the editor column in a proper format

Comment: Please check in your previous question where I already give answer using MVVM binding 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60391560/display-data-from-api-on-screen-in-a-decent-form

Comment: im trying to show it @Nikhileshwar

Comment: @Rajendra sir due respect im not using mvvm approach as it is not allowed for my project

Comment: @Sajawal Zubairi  Please look into my answer you will find solution of your question.

Comment: @PaulKertscher yes sir it is indeed page 2 xaml

Comment: i get the data on page 1 and store it in an object now i passed that object on a button click onto next page. So  now i want that json data to be shown on page 2. Page 1 has a button which navigates to page 2 including json data now i want that json data to be shown on page 2 xaml (repeated)

Answer (score 1):

Create new page send json data from your last page and populate here by belo code.

XAML code

```
<Grid Margin="20,50">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Editor Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="id" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    <Editor x:Name="txtId" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" IsReadOnly="True"/>

    <Editor Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="First name" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    <Editor x:Name="txtFirstname" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"  IsReadOnly="True"/>

    <Editor Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="Last name" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    <Editor x:Name="txtLastname"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"  IsReadOnly="True"/>

    <Editor Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Text="Email" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    <Editor x:Name="txtEmail" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"  IsReadOnly="True"/>

    <Editor Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Text="Image" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    <Image x:Name="imgUser" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" />

</Grid>
```

Code behind

```
public partial class Homepage : ContentPage
{
    private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    myuser _Data;
    public Homepage(myuser Data)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //this.BindingContext = new MainPageViewModel();
        _Data = Data;

    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        txtId.Text = _Data.id.ToString();
        txtFirstname.Text = _Data.first_name;
        txtLastname.Text = _Data.last_name;
        txtEmail.Text = _Data.email;
        imgUser.Source = _Data.avatar;
    }


}
```

Hope it will help you

Thanks

Comment: can this be more elaborate

Answer (score 0):

First, you can follow the MVVM pattern to make this easier in the long run.
But if you want to proceed with your existing code then you can try this:

First, setup your binding context in your Page 2 xaml:

```
<ContentPage x:Name="MyPage" ... />

<StackLayout Padding="20">
    <Editor BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=MyPage}" Text="{Binding obj.id}"   IsReadOnly="True"/>
    <Editor BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=MyPage}" Text="{Binding obj.first_name}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    <Editor BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=MyPage}" Text="{Binding obj.last_name}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    <Editor BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=MyPage}" Text="{Binding obj.email}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    <Editor BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=MyPage}" Text="Image" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    <Image x:Name="myImage" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100"/>

    <Label Text="show json"
        x:Name="displaylabel"
    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

</StackLayout>
```

In your code behind:

Instead of passing `string test`, you can declare a UserReponse object:

```
private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
public String test; //instead of this
public UserReponse result; //do this
```

Then modify this:

```
public async Task GetinfoAsync()
    {
        var responseString = await client.GetStringAsync("https://reqres.in/api/users/2");

        result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserResponse>(responseString); //modify to this

        if (result != null)
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                test = dis.Text = "Id:- " + result.Data.id + "\nEmail:- " + result.Data.email + "\nFirst Name:- " + result.Data.first_name + "\nLast Name:- " + result.Data.last_name + "\nImage:- " + result.Data.avatar; dis.Text = test;
            });
        }
    }
```

Then pass it:

```
 await this.Navigation.PushAsync(new Data(result));
```

Replace your page 2 code behind with:

```
public partial class Data : ContentPage
{

    private MyUser _obj;
    public MyUser obj
    {
       get{return _obj;}
       set
       {
          _obj = value;
          OnPropertyChanged();
       }
    }

    public String show;

    public Data(UserReponse result)
    {
        show = test;
        InitializeComponent();
        obj = result.Data;
        myImage.Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri(obj.avatar));
        displaylabel.Text = test;
    }
}
```

Comment: i can see every thing except image i cant see it

Comment: @SajawalZubairi I updated it for the image source. Kindly update your page 2 xaml and code behind.

Comment: myImage does not exist in the current context

Comment: @SajawalZubairi make sure you've changed this  <Image x:Name="myImage" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100"/>

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the UserResponse to the Data Page directly,and binding it to the page：

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
  private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  public UserResponse test;

  public MainPage()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    //     Task.Run(async () => await GetinfoAsync());
    GetinfoAsync();
  }

  public async Task GetinfoAsync()
  {
    var responseString = await client.GetStringAsync("https://reqres.in/api/users/2");

    UserResponse result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserResponse>(responseString);
    if (result != null)
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            test = result;
        });
    }
  }

  private async void click_me(Object sender, EventArgs args)
  {
    await this.Navigation.PushAsync(new Data(test));
  }
}
```

the Data page:

```
public partial class Data : ContentPage
{
  public UserResponse obj;
  public String show;

  public Data(UserResponse test)
  {
    obj= test;
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = obj;
  }
}
```

the xaml :

```
<StackLayout Padding="20">
  <Editor Text="{Binding Data.id}"   IsReadOnly="True"/>
  <Editor Text="{Binding Data.first_name}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
  <Editor Text="{Binding Data.last_name}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
  <Editor Text="{Binding Data.email}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
  <Editor Text="Image" IsReadOnly="True"/>
  <Image  HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" Source="{Binding Data.avatar}"/>

  <Label Text="show json"
    x:Name="displaylabel"
    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

</StackLayout>
```