# Display one JSON object in XAML

Tags: c#, json, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview

I'm failing to display one json object in XAML in xamarin.forms, everywhere i search there are only list or collection methods to display json in xaml. What I recieve is only one json object, and these (listview and collection) methods fail to display this object.

I managed to recieve the object json content in C#, so the only problem is to pass it to XAML so it could be displayed.

I'm starting to think that Xamarin.forms cannot display one json object, only lists.

There is also list of these Json objects which I successfully pass as table, so i tried to point to specific object (using its ID) `<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding List[4]}"` but that causes that neither list or that one object is displayed then.

Comment: I think you need override `ToString()` method of the model class then you can display your object as a string in XAML controls

Comment: of course it can.  Deserialize your json into a C# object and then bind it to your UI.

Answer (score 0):

Convert to string helped, thak you guys.
To be specific i used this [Show JSON response through binding (Xamarin forms)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60408013/show-json-response-through-binding-xamarin-forms)